# Wrap the textarea around a HTML element

Tags: html, css, textarea

Is there any way I can wrap a textarea HTML element around a HTML element? In my case I want to wrap the textarea around the label.

This is what I try to achieve:

```
Label name: *********
*********************
*********************
```

Where the * is the text area.

Comment: @Salman A, thanks for editing, I was struggling to make it look like that

Comment: not clear what you want, the textarea looks like a block with rectangular shape, it can't be treated as an inline element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use *HTML* tags inside `<textarea>` but you can use absolute positioning to place the label at the desired position.

Then, you can use the *CSS* `text-indent` property ([more info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)) to offset the first line of the textarea so the label doesn't overlap it.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 115px;
  line-height: 1em;
}

textarea {
  text-indent: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>This is the label :</label>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: 2 minutes faster than me!

Comment: @SalmanA that is pretty close! I was going to make the same edit as you on the question but you were faster then ^^

Comment: Wow, it works, I was clueless about that text-indent property. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could try to place the label in a div element, make the div editable and make the label un-editable ...

Something like this:

```
<div onClick="this.contentEditable='true';">
  <label onClick="this.contentEditable='false';">text 1</label>
  text 2
</div>
```

After that you just need to arrange your label and div with `css` and use the information inside the div (excluding the label) as the text inside a textbox.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HAj6B/) to take a look at how it would work.

Comment: @Nisha Thanks, I try to avoid positioning as much as possible to prevent it from going wrong on who knows what browser / OS. But I will admit the other answers don't have the problem of having to scrape some of the text.

Comment: The CSS solution is pretty solid and I want to use it for a Drupal website which wouldn't allow me to do that, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how well the `text-indent` property works on textarea elements. If it works well enough, you can do this:

- Align the label with top-left corner of textarea using positioning and set a fixed width
- Use `text-indent` property to indent the first line of text in textarea

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/85g94/2/)

```html
<div class="position-helper">
    <label>Label name:</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

```css
.position-helper {
    position: relative;
}
.position-helper label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    /* font-size normalized so that em values match */
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 10em;
}
textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* font-size normalized so that em values match */
    font-size: 16px;
    text-indent: 10em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `text-indent` Property. Modify the `text-indent` value as per your requirement.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <label><b>Label name:</b></label>
    <textarea name="textarea1" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="PlaceHolder Text For the Text Area"></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div 
{
    position:relative;
}
label {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border:0;
}
textarea {
    text-indent:90px;
    margin:0;
     border:1px solid blue;    
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: OUTPUT]