# Maintain constant padding in scrolling textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I'm designing a textarea with an icon in the upper left corner. To keep the text from entering the icon area the textarea is padded:

```
padding: 35px 10px 10px 10px;
```

[image: at the top]

However, when the quantity of text overflows the textarea, the text enters the padded area.

[image: overflow text]

Is there an elegant solution to keeping the text from flowing into this section without using too many extra elements?

Comment: you can check this similar question asked a few hours ago : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158683/wrap-the-textarea-around-a-html-element/24158860#24158860 and please add relevant code (HTML/CSS) to your question

Comment: @web-tiki AFAIK text indent only works on the first line of text, so the text will still scroll into the area.

Comment: It might be nice having a white drop shadow to the icon and so the text would hide under it's immediate glow around it.. but if you wanted the whole line of text to overflow under the icon.. that's different.. what would you prefer?

Comment: @web-tiki There isn't really any relevant CSS other than what I have posted. It's a standard `textarea` with an absolutely positioned `icon` and some padding.

Comment: yes, that is why I didn't mark as duplicate still, can you please share your code so we can give a consistent asnwer

Comment: is the icon an icon-font?

Comment: @webkit Nice idea, I'll see how that looks. It's font-awesome.

Comment: cool, if it's a font play around with text-shadow.. or maybe a cooler effect would be to give it a round linear background that way fading out the opacity of mask gradually.. let me know how it turns out

Comment: @webkit I can't seem to get a decent result with text-shadow. You can always see the text beneath too clearly.

Comment: than try the other option.. using a wrapping div with a linear gradient background.. you want me to post an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a gradient background on your icon element:

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 33%,rgba(255,255,255,0.03) 98%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
```

here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sFM7C/74/)

Gradient was generated with http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

so all the many lines of css there is just for the cross browser application of the same gradient..
You can play around with it to get the exact effect you're looking for..

what do u think? :)